# Folder Specific IAM Permissions for boto3 S3 API Calls

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

So I have a user whose IAM permissions are set to the following.  It is meant to only allow them Create/Delete/List/etc. objects in the "Target_Folder/" for the bucket.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt123456789",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/Target_Folder/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using boto3, I embed the relevant aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key in the config.  After doing this, I find I am unable to preform any actions within the "/Target_Folder/" such as:

```
import boto3
import boto.s3.transfer
#Need to manually import S3Transfer() for some reason.
from boto.s3.transfer import S3Transfer 

bucket = 'bucket'
prefix = 'Test_Folder/'

client = boto3.client(s3)

#Attempt to print objects under the Target_Folder
response = client.list_objects(Bucket = bucket, Prefix = prefix)
for file in response['Contents']:
    print(file['key'])


#Attempt to upload file
transfer = S3Transfer(client)
transfer.upload_file('C:/filepath/file', bucket, prefix)
```

Ultimately, no matter what approach, I receive a `"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occured (SignatureDoesNotMatch)...."`.  Conversely, if I use a key/secret_key pair with much more open bucket permissions, I have no issues interacting with the API.

Apologies if this has been answered or clarified in another thread, I could not find any good ones while searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the s3 bucket `bucket` should exist.

You need to assign `s3:ListBucket` permission on the s3 bucket, then you can give the object access permission in this bucket

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Action":[
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:GetBucketLocation"
       ],
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt123456789",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket",   # and this should be removed.
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/Target_Folder/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```